# Если интернет теряет связь то пусть переподключается

Tags: python, binance

В общем пишу код. И иногда если на долго оставляю то выдает ошибки из за проблемы со связью. Как прописать на Python что бы он переподключался если инернет был оборван?
может обрывается из за этого кода?:

```
client = Client(api_key, secret_key, {"timeout": 20})
```

стоит таймаут 20?
выдает вот такую ошибку: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: try/except? и в except переподключиться

Comment: как это вписать? можете пример написать кода

Answer (score 0):

Я предположу, что у вас там цикл while True.
В таком случае можно сделать:

```
try: 
    #ваш код
except: continue
```

Если же все не в цикле, можно попробовать увеличить timeout, или же поставить try/except на каждый post запрос (ошибка возникает именно там)

Comment: в рекомендациях было сказано использовать (verify:true, timeout:20) для чего используется verify?

Comment: verify и так по умолчанию True, а используется он для проверки ssl-сертификата (если подключение небезопасно - не подключается и уходит в ошибку SSLerror)

Comment: а ничего что я указал  timeout:none  вместо 20 что бы он постоянно переподключался или лучше вернуть 20?

Comment: Timeout не так работает) Он не будет переподключаться, он вылетит в ошибку. Можно сделать поменьше и кинуть в try/except, или же побольше и надеяться что он сможет все-таки подключиться

Comment: Значит вернуть родные 20 найстроки и в try: exept: continue сделать